# That's all they pick on now. (To Have and Have Not by Hemingway)

Tags: meaning

This is from Ernest Hemingway's *To Have and Have Not.*

I don't understand the meaning of the following: "That's all they pick on now. Any kind of sporting people. Anybody with any sort of a cheerful outlook."

“They tell me they ain’t going to let no girls out on the streets after six o’clock at night and no girls in any of the places,” Freddy says to Big Lucie’s daughter. 
“That’s what they say.”
“It’s getting to be a hell of a town,” Freddy says. 
“Hell of a town is right. You just walk outside to get a sandwich and a coca-cola and they arrest you and fine you fifteen dollars.”
“That’s all they pick on now,” says Big Lucie’s daughter. “Any kind of sporting people. Anybody with any sort of a cheerful outlook.”
“If something don’t happen to this town pretty quick things are going to be bad.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"That's all they pick on now."

Freddy feels that the town and regulations of the town are picking [treating them unfairly] on the sporting people [people who like to go out and have a good time - party-people].  He is mad about the curfew the town is imposing on him, when he thinks it is his right to be out on the town.